# sample project for Expandable TableVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create something like below.

[image]

Is there any sample code available that I can use?

I saw [JKExpandTableView](http://jackkwok.github.io/JKExpandTableView/), but its little more confusing.

Is there any simple code for what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some basic example at below link.

http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/

This is very easy to implement...

Answer (score 0):

You can put this sort of thing together easily with [TLIndexPathTools](http://tlindexpathtools.com). It provides some lower-level components for doing dynamic things with tables.

Take a look at the ["Collapse" sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Collapse/Collapse/CollapseTableViewController.m). It does expandable sections. There's also the ["Outline" sample project](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools/blob/master/Examples/Outline/Outline/OutlineTableViewController.m) that does expandable trees.